# Status of EOS Powerup feature

Tags: eosjs, eosio-code

I have following questions on [EOS Powerup](https://eos.io/news/eos-powerup-model-explained/):

1. Is the [EOS Powerup](https://eos.io/news/eos-powerup-model-explained/) model optional?
2. When is this expected to go live? The [link](https://eosauthority.com/powerup/) here mentions April 8 where as https://eosauthority.com/powerup/ mentions that it has been already activated for ~14 days. But, the FAQ on same page mentions that it will be coming soon. What is the correct status of powerup.
3. Once powerup goes live, for how long will the old model be supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes and no. When fully activated, 99% of CPU/NET will come from PowerUP, 1% from traditional staking. If you need very little CPU, then you can stake as before.  Generally you will need to use PowerUp or use a wallet that uses PowerUp on your behalf.
2. It is live already. Resources are being transitioned from staking to PowerUp over a few weeks. It will be complete (99%) in April 2021.
3. No planned date to remove the 1% of resources in the old staking model.

Comment: Thank you for your response Matthew.

Is there a transition guide that can be referred to transition currently staked coins to power up model? I am looking for steps and exmaples that I can use.

Comment: https://t.me/eosresourcemodel

Answer (score 0):

Aaron Cox (jesta) — Greymass, [06.03.21 16:24]
I worked pretty much all week refining the powerup calculations in:

https://github.com/greymass/eosio-resources

It's in a decent place now I think. There's a ton of methods exposed by its APIs to do conversions, which are exposed through the library and are viewable here:

https://github.com/greymass/eosio-resources/blob/master/src/powerup/cpu.ts

Which extends an abstract class that has additional calls that are shared between cpu/net:

https://github.com/greymass/eosio-resources/blob/master/src/powerup/abstract.ts